# Why is Flattening a CoefficientArray so slow?

Tags: sparse-arrays, performance-tuning, list-manipulation

I have a vector of $n$ degree $n$ polynomials in $(x,y,z)$, each of whose coefficients is an inhomogenous linear expression in $3 n^2$ variables. I want to write down the linear equations in these $3 n^2$ variables which say that all these coefficients are identically zero. Here $n$ is about $15$. I used to be doing this with a combination of various `Map[]`, `Coefficient[]` and `CoefficientList[]` commands, but the result was much slower than I wanted.

Tonight, I discovered the `CoefficientArrays[]` command in the documentation, which seemed built for exactly this job. To my surprise, I found that replacing one of my `Coefficient[]` calls with `CoefficientArray[]` was a dramatic improvement, but replacing the other `CoefficientList[]` was a disaster.

Of course, I know what to do: Replace the good one but not the bad one! But I am curious why.

The following code sets up test data. In the actual use, `f` and `PolyBasis` are not random polynomials but part of a larger computation, but I found that I could use random data for profiling without changing the speed:

```
n = 15;

f = Sum[Random[] x^i y^j z^(n - i - j), {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n - i}];
PolyBasis = Table[Sum[Random[] x^i y^j z^(n-1 - i - j), {i, 0, n-1}, {j, 0, 
    n-1 - i}], {n}];

AA = Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
BB = Table[b[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
CC = Table[c[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];

MM = x AA + y BB + z CC;

LeftKer = MM.PolyBasis - Prepend[ConstantArray[0, n - 1], f];
```

Here is what I used to be doing:

```
AbsoluteTiming[EqL = Flatten[Map[CoefficientList[#, {x, y, z}] &, LeftKer]];]
   (* {0.562461, Null} Kind of slow. *)

shortEqL = Select[EqL, ! (# === 0) &]; 

vars = Flatten[Join[
  Table[a[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}],
  Table[b[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}],
  Table[c[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]];

AbsoluteTiming[Big = Map[Coefficient[#, vars] &, shortEqL];]
  (* {20.197230, Null} REALLY SLOW *)

AbsoluteTiming[small = shortEqL /. Map[(# -> 0) &, vars];]
  (* {3.257321, Null} Significantly slow *)
```

Replacing the last two commands with `CoefficientArrays[]` is a huge gain:

```
AbsoluteTiming[{small2, Big2} = CoefficientArrays[shortEqL, vars];]
  (* {0.105790, Null} Yippee! *)
```

Replacing the "kind of slow" command with CoefficientArrays gains a little:

```
AbsoluteTiming[EqL2=CoefficientArrays[LeftKer, {x, y, z}];]
  (* {0.401718, Null} *)
```

But `Flatten[EqL2]` runs for many minutes without stopping, as does `Normal[EqL2]`!

**Question:** Why is `Flatten[]`ing the output of `CoefficientArrays[]` so bad? And is there something smart I should be doing to improve on `EqL = Flatten[Map[CoefficientList[#, {x, y, z}] &, LeftKer]];`?

For the curious, we are trying to remove some of the bottlenecks in the algorithm described [here](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~plaumann/PSSV12.pdf).

Comment: The link to http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~plaumann/PSSV12.pdf seems to be broken.

Answer (score 7):

When you are flattening the expression, you are asking Mathematica to reserve memory for *at least*

```
Total@Cases[EqL2, SparseArray[x_, y_, z__] :> Times @@ y]
(*322850400 elements *)
```

To be more precise, you are only filling

```
Length@Select[Flatten@Cases[EqL2, s_SparseArray :> ArrayRules@s] /. 
                                                 Rule -> List, ! FreeQ[#, a | b | c] &]
(* 2040 elements*)
```

with your coefficients, and the rest seems being filled with zeroes.

Perhaps you may use  `ArrayRules[]` and keep the Sparse Arrays instead of normalizing them.